# How to make Button event trigger call methods from my instantiated objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In my mobile game (2d side scroller), my player character movements (left , right and jump) are manipulated through buttons with event triggers by utilizing its pointer up (). the catch is, I have a scene before the actual game that lets the player select different character objects then it will instantiate on the actual game scene.

I'm aware that a button needs an object reference slot field where it can call the method of movements from my character script but I can only reference one since there are other possible character objects that relies on that button for movements. Is there a way where I can write a script that when I press my movement buttons, those buttons can recognize and call my movement script from my instantiated character gameObjects without referencing character object on the button event trigger reference slot? Thank you

Here is What I have done so far:

```
 public class TestPlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] public float movespeed;
Rigidbody2D rb;
float xAxisMove;
bool moveleft;
bool moveright;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}


private void Update()
{
 MovePlayerXAxis();
}


public void PointerUpleft() {
    moveleft = false;
}

public void PointerDownleft()
{
    moveleft = true;
}

public void PointerDownRight()
{
    moveright = true;
}

public void PointerUpRight()
{
    moveright = false;
}

//Checks if player will move left or right
void MovePlayerXAxis() {
    if (moveleft)
    {
        xAxisMove = -1;
    }
    else if (moveright)
    {
        xAxisMove = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        xAxisMove = 0;
    }

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(xAxisMove * movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
}
```

}

This is the outcome I would liek to have: [image]

I hope this flow will you understand my post, thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a Singleton object, and have it store a reference list or cache.

### Your Singleton Class:

```
public class SomeSingletonClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static SomeSingletonClass instance;

    // List of game objects you can store to reference it later
    private List<GameObject> refList = new List<GameObject>();

    public static SomeSingletonClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = FindObjectOfType<SomeSingletonClass>();

                if (instance == null)
                {
                    GameObject singletonObject = new GameObject("SomeSingletonClass");
                    instance = singletonObject.AddComponent<SomeSingletonClass>();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void AddToRefList(GameObject obj)
    {
        if (!refList.Contains(obj))
        {
            refList.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public List<GameObject> GetRefList()
    {
        // Ideally for best practices, you wouldn't want anyone to directly access this list.
        return refList;
    }
}
```

### Creation Class

```
private void CreateObject()
{
    GameObject yourNewObject = Instantiate(/*...*/);
    // Add the newly instantiated object to the global list.
    SomeSingletonClass.Instance.AddToRefList(yourNewObject);
}
```

### Creation Class

```
private void OnClickStuff()
{
    // Now you have a list of gameobjects that you can call methods on.
    List<GameObject> callMethodsOn = SomeSingletonClass.Instance.GetRefList();
}
```

> Here are [a few](https://gamedevbeginner.com/singletons-in-unity-the-right-way/) different [links](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern) to learn [more about](https://awesometuts.com/blog/singletons-unity/) singleton. It should be quite straight forward as it is just a static object, without it being static.

Comment: do I create this singleton object on the actual game scene? sorry I'm quite a beginner on this. Thank you.

Comment: @RyanCat Yes, there will be a GameObject on the actual game scene with the attached Singleton script on it. You can see https://youtu.be/CPKAgyp8cno for better understanding. The Youtube video shows how Singleton can be used to make an integer value globally accessible, which you can change it to any other data-type *(list, GameObject, etc)*.

Comment: Does the concept of this approach is where my selected instantiated character object will be identified by the movement buttons as a same object regardless of what character I selected? thank you for the responses by the way.

Comment: @RyanCat, I am not sure what you are asking. As long as you add the GameObject to the Singleton on initialization, the Singleton will always have the reference to the GameObject, regardless of player interactions. You would need to have additional code to change/remove the reference to the GameObject.

Comment: @RyanCat I have created a simple project to show you the Singleton: https://gitlab.com/stack-overflow-examples/singleton-example-76840757 ; The left button creates a object randomly in the world, and stores it to the Singleton. The second button tells the Singleton to delete all of it's stored objects. You can view the code in the link provided.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it out to the actual application, I will let you know as soon as possible on my progress.

Comment: Hi, I just checked out the project in which I appreciated you had done, however I can't see how it can create a way where I can control movements of an instantiated prefab (character object)  via UI buttons.

Comment: @RyanCat Have methods on the reference object or the singleton, to move the object, and call the methods when the button gets pressed.

Comment: Thanks for helping sir, kinda solve it by using unity input system by following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF4tGpgEPuI,  and your approach is a bonus as I can use the singleton on a different mechanics for my game.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a button event trigger to call methods from your instantiated objects. There are a few ways you can do this, depending on the specific requirements of your project.

One approach is to use the `EventTrigger` script in Unity, which allows you to call a method of a child component when an event is triggered, such as a button click or mouseover. You can find more information about the `EventTrigger` script in the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.html).

Another approach is to use the `onClick` event of the button to call a method that references your instantiated objects. This method could then call the appropriate methods on those objects. You can find more information about using the `onClick` event in this [Unity forum post](https://discussions.unity.com/t/unity-5-0-2f1-ui-button-onclick-function/139532).

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a simple example how to apply this? I'm new to this and not quite familiar on the terms being used on the documentation that I have read. Yes I want to use a button event trigger to call methods from my instantiated objects and to specifically call a specific method like for example: call the left method from the left button using event trigger.